# Copy/Paste - OverWrite into a file which is under VSS

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I have some files under VSS - If I copy an updated version of a file into its location and overwrite it , will VSS update iteself / reflect the updated file ?

Seems that when I do this, the updated code is not being reflected within the file in VSS and also when somebody else pulls down the file they dont get the updates ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing a VSS-controlled file locally on your hard drive (by copying/pasting) requires that you:

1. Check out the file first. (If you don't do that and try only to remove the read-only flag, your changes won't be reflected on the VSS database upon check in)
2. Paste your desired copy of the file (overwriting the previously checked-out file)
3. Then check in the file, which would overwrite the file version in the VSS database.

So, when other users try to get the latest version, they'd get your checked-in version.